# php regular expression match any word characters except numbers

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation

I need to get everything from this regular expression except numbers, how can i do it ?

```
^[\w'-`´]{1,50}$
```

So, the problem here is that \w matches numbers too, a and i don't want it to match numbers. I want the regular expression returning everything that is already returning except the numbers!

Comment: everthing FROM this regexp? Please clearify your question

Comment: i need a regular expression similar to this one that returns the same characters without numbers

Comment: this regular expression includes ZàáâãäçèéêëìíîïñòóôõöùúûüýÿÀÁÂÃÄÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝ for example

Comment: You just want a-z and A-Z?

Comment: i want '-`´plus the characters the \w matches without numbers

Comment: I don't know almost anything about regex, but you could use this in addition: `preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);` and check the size of `$matches`

Comment: that's an idea, but i would prefer all in one regex that returns a string also, i think your idea gives me an array

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would work:

```
^(?=\D+$)[\w'`´-]{1,50}$
```

This will first assert that there are no digits in the string, then use your current check.

The `-` has been moved to the end, otherwise it has special meaning. Thanks MikeM for pointing that out.

Comment: the problem is that this also matches []()*? etc, etc

Comment: Because the `'-\`` creates a range. Best to put the `-` at the end of the `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

> I want '-`´ plus the characters that \w matches without numbers

What's wrong with this if you want the specific characters and what `\w` matches except for numbers?

```
^[a-zA-Z'`´_-]{1,50}$
```